# Why # Bytes in all Heaps considered good measure for overall managed heap

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, performancecounter

I am monitoring my .NET application high memory issue using performance counters. For measuring .NET memory, my impression was that **# Bytes in all Heaps** performance counter provides overall managed memory usage. However according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc(v=vs.100).aspx), this counter does not include Gen 0 Heap Size.

> Displays the sum of the Gen 1 Heap Size, Gen 2 Heap Size, and Large
>   Object Heap Size counters. This counter indicates the current memory
>   allocated in bytes on the garbage collection heaps.

If a .NET application is allocating lot of memory in Gen 0, then shouldn't this be accounted for in # Bytes in all Heaps also? I know there is a separate counter for Gen 0 heap size but so do for Gen 1, Gen 2 and LoH as well.

Comment: You cannot allocate "huge memory" in gen 0.  Large allocations are made on the Large Object Heap.  The name is not a coincidence.

Comment: Take a memory dump at a high memory point and analyze it with WinDbg or a profiler. This will tell you what uses all the memory.

Comment: Sorry I meant lots of allocations that are not necessarily large to go on LOH. Sorry about my English but I always struggle with using appropriate wordings :) I hopefully have clarified it in my question now

Comment: That also isn't going to happen - everytime something survives a collection, it's pushed one generation up. And of course, if it doesn't survive, it's going to be freed :) Gen 0 is always going to be quite small (and fickly).

Comment: @xxbbcc point of questions is to understand if # of Bytes in all hypes is a true representation of managed heap

Comment: @HansPassant Does this mean Gen 0 allocation has any upper threshold and it cannot go over that threshold size?

Comment: Well, do you care about the memory used by thread stacks, for example? Or the application image? Those usually contribute more to the memory footprint than Gen 0 heap(s).

Comment: @johnsmith In that case you should read the documentation on the garbage collection and how allocations are organized.

Comment: @xxbbcc that's question I have in mind after reading some documenation

Comment: @johnsmith Then grab a memory dump and look at it with WinDbg. It shows exactly what goes into which heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly subjective.  But when you ask the question "how much memory does my .NET application use" then you are not typically interested in the memory allocations that live for a millisecond or less.  The "working memory" so to speak.  Used by the kind of objects that are stored in the gen #0 heap segment.

Only when such objects live long enough, and thus get promoted to higher generations, could you start worrying that maybe your app is not using memory efficiently.  Never ever worry about gen #0.

Non-zero odds that another practicality played a role.  If the counter would also show gen #0 then it would be a wildly changing number that very rapidly bounces up and down.  Basically white noise in a graph, not very friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "Gen 0 Heap Size" doesn't tell you how much bytes the objects in Gen 0 heap take up - it's always preallocated to a certain size and doesn't grow during allocations. The number just tells you how much memory is preallocated for Gen 0 allocations.

There isn't really a real-time way to get the size of objects in Gen 0 - it's a bit too high traffic to make it worth it. In comparison, both the Gen 1 and Gen 2 heaps can only ever be populated during a garbage collection - it's trivial to set a performance counter there. The LOH has similar reasoning - you're allocating large enough objects, so the cost of incrementing the performance counter is mostly trivial.

Don't forget that Gen 0 objects can't stay in Gen 0 for long - during the next collection, they're either going to be freed or moved to Gen 1. It's hard to imagine a scenario where the Gen 0 heap is heavily populated - in fact, IIRC, it is scaled relative to the CPU cache; while that isn't exactly "small" on modern CPUs, it also shows the intent clearly - it's a scratch book for a couple of small objects that are either thrown away almost immediately, or moved away.